# Limit in Mails from an ip

Tags: email, ip

I would like to host an application that sends mails for verification, forgot password etc...Is there a limit in the number of mails sent from an ip address??..Is there any way to overcome this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your ISP and the receivers' ISPs. Technically, there is of course no limit. But your ISP might think you're sending spam, so it's good to inform him that this is not the case.

Much harder is to convince the receivers' ISPs that you're not sending spam. I had problems with gmx, a large German ISP: they were not accepting more than so-and-so many (maybe some 1000) mails from me to non-existant accounts per 24h. That sounds a lot, but since I was sending a large mailing list, there were always too many no-longer existant email addresses.

As far as I know, there was no way of convincing gmx that I was not sending any spam, but a newsletter. I don't think they have a procedure for that. So, unless you are *really* important, they will just ignore you.

And then there are open blocklists, like spamhaus, that might somehow list you. They might be used by many ISPs around the world. In such a case, you can usually contact them and have your record cleared.

Comment: What can I do in case I am taking a hosting service??...Can the 3rd party hosting restrict my mails??..In case of dedicated/shared hosting I wont be knowing any details about the ISP or anything..

Comment: Well, in that case I would assume you have a high degree of freedom. But who knows? I cannot tell you from experience.